# VisibilityOfElementLocated selenium java not working with phantomjs driver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, phantomjs, wait

I'm running the following code with chrome driver in selenium with java and it works just fine for me:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3);
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("buttontofind")));
driver.findElement(By.id("buttontofind")).click();
```

However, when I changed **chromedriver** with **phantomjsdriver**, and try to execute it I am getting the following error message:

```
Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: buttontofind (tried for 3 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the following:

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("buttontofind")).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
```

Was not done enough times with phantomjs, it worked with chrome with less arrow downs it seems...

Comment: try to use headless chrome